# Vue3/Pinia: Adding main store to each component: mainStore() or Provide/Inject?

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Default way to add a pinia store to Vue3 component is through loading nameStore.js in each Vue3 component

```
import {nameStore} from "@stores/nameStore.js"
const nameStr = nameStore()
```

Vue3 has it's own Provide/Inject.

Which approach is better for the main pinia store that's used in almost all major components? (but not much used in small components)

Comment: There is no default way. Both of them will give the same result. Use which way gives you more comfortable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally there is no differece between your two options, as already stated by @Duannx. It comes down to preferences.

When using provide/inject you avoid the import statement and the function call, reducing the boilerplate to a single line `const nameStore = inject('nameStore')`, the drawbacks are the usual ones that come with provide/inject:

- It leads to tight coupling between your components, making them less reusable in other contexts. However, if you inject your store at the root component of your app, this won't matter much.
- There is no compile-time safety: If the store was not provided correctly, your `inject` call will return `undefined`, which will only be found out during runtime.

IMO the "normal" way of importing and calling the store hook has no similar problems, so I would generally suggest to use it rather than provide/inject, which adds (again, IMO) unnecessary complexity.  But as I said, ultimately it's a matter of taste :)